# Azure Vnet Peering in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have a common ARM template for common infrastructure and a ARm template for applicationXYZ infrastructure.

In the arm template for applicationXYZ infrastructure I want to peer a vnet in it to a vnet in the common infrastructure ARM template. Is it possible to do so without editing both ARM templates, or having the vnets peered in the same ARM template?

Comment: May you want to find a template like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vnet-to-vnet-peering).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question properly, but if the vnets are in different resource groups you need nested deployment or change both templates to create peering, as peering require to be configured on both end (with the exclusing of classic to arm peering, it can be enabled on one end).

Also, you cannot create a peering if a vnet is not existant, so in order for your idea to work the vnets must be in place.